# How does the CLR marshal a structure containing only a single field when calling unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, pinvoke, marshalling

By default, how will the CLR marshal a structure that contains only a single field, but defines multiple methods, properties, operators, etc., when calling an unmanaged function through P/Invoke?
A simplified version of the structure in question might look something like the following:

```
public struct SimpleStruct
{
    private IntPtr _value;

    public SimpleStruct(IntPtr value)
    {
       this._value = value;
    }

    public int MyMethod()
    {
       return 42;
    }
}
```

The specific unmanaged function being called here is irrelevant, so for the sake of discussion, just assume something simple from the Windows API, like this one:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool IsWindow(SimpleStruct hWnd);
```

**In particular, I'm interested in whether the structure gets marshaled as if it were an `IntPtr` type, or if the CLR attempts to marshal the structure as it would a more complex structure with multiple fields.** I realize that "under the hood", *all* primitive types (including `IntPtr` and `Int32`) are implemented as structures. But I am not sure if there's some special-casing built in that handles these "known" structures representing primitive types differently than it would handle a custom-defined one.

I understand that *only* the fields within the type are accessible, and any methods, properties, or events are inaccessible from unmanaged code, and that's exactly what I want. I'd like to get the above structure marshaled to the unmanaged function exactly the same way as if the declaration were rewritten to specify a parameter of type `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

---

Corollarily, does the behavior change when adding the following attributes to the structure's definition?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct OtherStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private IntPtr _value;

    public SimpleStruct(IntPtr value)
    {
       this._value = value;
    }

    public int MyMethod()
    {
       return 42;
    }
}
```

I've only ever used the [`FieldOffsetAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute.aspx) when simulating a union (i.e., multiple fields), but I've seen this done in some of Microsoft's own code, ostensibly to achieve the behavior I ask about above.

Is there any difference in the case where only a single field is defined? Or does this just make the default behavior more explicit?

Comment: Since a struct with just one field is stored in memory the same as just that field would be, I can't imagine that the Interop system would do anything different with one vs. the other.

Comment: @Gabe: That's my gut feeling, too. And everything "works" just fine. I'm more curious about the implementation details, and thus whether there's a potential performance or other hidden penalty I might have to pay for later. [This site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t2cwe11.aspx) is partially what makes me question that assumption—see the section on "System Value Types" that indicates `System.Int32` is marshaled as `ELEMENT_TYPE_I4` "instead of as a structure containing a single member of type `long`".

Comment: The part of the passage that says "you marshal them in the same way ..." indicates to me that it's just saying that you can use `System.Int32` to send data to a C function that expects a `long`; you don't have to write your C function to expect a `struct { long }`.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your question about implicit/explicit:

This will result in the exact same thing. The default [LayoutKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) (for C#) is Sequential, and the first element in a struct with this layout is [always at offset 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx). (The following elements' positions will depend on the packing chosen, as described in the second link.)